New passport for Schengen travel
Schengen area visa allows visits of up to 90 days in any 180-day period. Can one bypass these restrictions by applying for a new passport, which won't have the stamps from previous visits?

Oh no! You are the first one thinking about this! Sorry, the answer is still no, the limit is for you, not your passport.

Don’t forget that countries get data on air or ship travellers from Advance Passenger Information.

The rules are about persons, not passport. So also using a different country passport want help. Possibly nobody will find it out, but if it happens, it will a big red flag on applying any visas in many/most countries.


Can one bypass these restrictions by applying for a new passport, which won't have the stamps from previous visits?

At present this is theoretically possible.
But when the Entry/Exit system is introduced (now expected for November 2024), this will no longer be possible.
With this system the biometerics of the person will be checked when entering or leaving and the dates stored. There will be no passport stamps (other than for special situations).
A new passport will not help, since the person themselves will not change.

Are past visits already recorded in the EES in addition to the stamps or does this only apply to visits beginning from Nov 2024?

In other words: do they already have the records and will start checking it in Nov 2024 - or will they only start recording in Nov 2024?

@notahamburger Article 12a (1) of the Schengen Border code only states: the border guards shall take into account the stays on the territory of the Member States during the 180 days preceding the entry or the exit by checking the stamps in the travel documents in addition to the entry/exit data recorded in the EES.
